# IBM x3650 M3 - Boot failed. Hard disk 0

Tags: ibm-server

After installing 12G RAM, the server boot failed. It says, "Boot Failed, Hard Disk 0 UEFI PXE PciRoot (0x0)/Pci(0x1, 0x0)/Pci(0x1, 0x0)/MAC(E324F1369S5C4, 0x0)) "

When I changed the RAM back the server still has the same issue - boot failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the hard drive connection? You could have knocked or dislodged it while fitting the ram.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have checked the two drives and they are online. All green lights flashing , no indicated errors or yellow lights. What do you mean knocked or dislodged? Do you mean to unplug drives while fitting the RAM?